# Pointer array to (with pointer array defined) strings: Are the strings stored sequential in memory?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

I wondering about how strings are stored in memory, when define them with/through an array of pointers, which point to them.

For example:

```
char *pa[] = { "Hello World!", "foo","bar","huhu","Let´s talk about that" };
```

Are the strings (or better: their characters) stored sequential in memory, one after another?

Like, for example in this case:

The first character byte of the second string `"foo"` which is `f` is stored directly inside the byte after the `\0`-Null character of the first string `"Hello World!"`.

OR

Are the strings stored separated in memory?, like for example:

`\0`-Null character of the first string `"Hello World!"` - sequence of Bytes between - `f` character of second string `"foo"`?

OR

Is it even so, that the storage is dependent from the situation, compiler, platform, etc. and its one time directly-sequential and one time not?

Can it furthermore occure also, that f.e. the first character `f` of the second string `"foo"` is stored directly after the `\0`-character of the first string `"Hello World!"`, meaning they are stored sequential, and between the `\0`-character of the second string `"foo"` and the first character of the third string `"bar"`, which is `b` is a gap of to the string-group non-affiliated bytes, dependent from the compiler, platform, etc.?

Question is for C and C++, as i work with both. If the answers between those two alter, please mention which language is in focus.

Hope you can understand, what i mean. Thank you very much for any answer.

Comment: They are not necessarily sequential, the compiler has freedom to decide

Comment: *Is it even so, that the storage is dependent from the situation, compiler, platform, etc.* Yes.  Exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot assume anything. It is implementation-defined whether they are stored in contiguous memory or not.

If you really want the strings to be like that, try

```
const char *base = "hello\0foo\0bar";
const char *hello = base;
const char *foo = base + 6; // hello + strlen(hello) + 1
const char *bar = base + 10; // foo + strlen(foo) + 1
```

or, as @SteveSummit suggests

```
const char *pa[] = { base, base + 6, base + 10 };
```

Comment: Or `char *pa[] = { base, base + 6, base + 10 };`

Comment: @pmg '@Steve Summit' That is a very clever alternative. Did not know that this is possible. I have 2 Questions about that: 1. Is this technique practicable on only C89 conform compilers, too? or is this a technique which belongs to newer standards? 2. Should i declare the pointers to strings ever as `const char` as you two did, if the strings are constant?

Comment: 1. yes, technique is valid for all C implementations since C89 or even earlier. 2. `const char *` is a defense against shooting yourself in the foot; you're free to copy the literal to a proper changeable array: `char base[] = "hello\0foo\0bar"; /* beware of changes to '\0's */`

Comment: Also note that `pa[ N ]` is equal to `&( pa[ N - 1 ] ) + strlen( pa[ N - 1 ] ) + 1`. It might be possible to create a C++ initializer using that fact that would enable modification if the `base` initializer "string" without requiring any code changes to the following code.

Answer (score 3):

Furthermore, if you had

```
char *pa[] = { "testing", "testing", "more testing" };
```

it would be possible for the compiler to store just one copy of the string `"testing"`, and point to it from both `pa[0]` and `pa[1]`.  (In fact, I just tried it with two modern compilers, and both of them did exactly that.)

Theoretically it would be possible for a really clever compiler to store just the string `"more testing"` and have `pa[0]` and `pa[1]` point into the middle of it.

I assume you were asking out of curiosity, but if by any chance you were thinking of writing code that somehow depended on the ordering of string constants in memory, the immediate and simple answer is: *Don't*.

Comment: And if multiple strings are stored, they could be in any order, or far apart from each other.

Answer (score 2):

What Steve Summit answered, plus: If multiple strings are stored, they could be in any order, or far apart from each other.

In addition, comparing pointers to these strings using ">", ">=" etc. is undefined behaviour. So you *may* check for example if p1 = "testing", p2 = "testing", whether p2 == p1 + 8 (which will produce 0 or 1 without any guarantees), but not whether p2 >= p1 + 8.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, the memory layout is implementation defined.

Extending [*pmg*'s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58472476/694576) and doing C you could do it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

char ** create_pointer_array_pointing_to_sequential_data(char ** ppa)
{
  char ** result = NULL;

  if (NULL == ppa)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t s = 0;
    size_t l = 0;

    while (NULL != ppa[l])
    {
      s += strlen(ppa[l]);
      ++l;
    }

    result = malloc((l + 1) * sizeof *result);
    if (NULL != result)
    {
      result[0] = malloc(s + l + 1);
      if (NULL != result[0])
      {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        {
          strcpy(result[i], ppa[i]);
          result[i + 1] = result[i] + strlen(result[i]) + 1;
        }

        result[l] = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
        int errno_save = errno;
        free(result);
        errno = errno_save;
        result = NULL;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Use it like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** create_pointer_array_pointing_to_sequential_data(char ** ppa);

int main(void)
{
  char ** pa = create_pointer_array_pointing_to_sequential_data(
    (char*[]){"Hello World!",
      "foo",
      "bar",
      "huhu",
      "Let's talk about that",
      NULL}
    );

   if (NULL == pa)
   {
     perror("create_pointer_array_pointing_to_sequential_data() failed");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   for (size_t i = 0; NULL != pa[i]; ++i)
   {
     printf("pa[%zu] starts at %p and ends at %p: %s\n", 
       i, (void*) pa[i], (void*)(pa[i] + strlen(pa[i])), pa[i]);
   }
 }
```

And get:

```
pa[0] starts at 0x6000003f0 and ends at 0x6000003fc: Hello World!
pa[1] starts at 0x6000003fd and ends at 0x600000400: foo
pa[2] starts at 0x600000401 and ends at 0x600000404: bar
pa[3] starts at 0x600000405 and ends at 0x600000409: huhu
pa[4] starts at 0x60000040a and ends at 0x600000420: Let's talk about that
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very extensive method for achieving that. I still fighting me through to understand every aspect of the algorithm in total. Thank you for this.